# How to read the status of a radio button using Xamarin UITest in a Xamarin Forms iOS App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I am unable to read the status of a radio button on iOS.
On Android, all is fine, my code is as follows:

```
bool isOn = false;
if (OnAndroid)
{
    var value = app.Query(x => switchQuery(x).Invoke("isChecked"));
    if (value.Length > 0)
    {
        isOn = Convert.ToBoolean(value[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

On iOS I have tried

```
var value = app.Query(x => switchQuery(x).Invoke("isOn"));
var value = app.Query(x => switchQuery(x).Invoke("isSelected"));
var value = app.Query(x => switchQuery(x).Invoke("isOn").Value<object>()).First();
var value = app.Query(x => switchQuery(x).Invoke("isSelected").Value<object>()).First();
```

My query result on iOS, regardless of the radio button being selected or not, is "*****"

Hoping somebody has gotten this working and can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you try to call `app.Query(c => c.Switch("radioButton").Property("isOn",true))` ?

Comment: That query return 0 results.

Comment: Is it always returning 0 ?

Comment: using app.Repl() may point you in the right direction and then using that to query the state of your radio control may provide you with what you are looking for